# Why do reference variables need to be initialized at definition?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, standards

I've tried searching around for the answer, but no luck so far. My question is - why must reference variables need to be initialized when they are defined? Is it a technical reason, or is it just something the standard doesn't allow?

Take this code for example:

```
int number = 42;
int& numberRef;
numberRef = number;
```

Above isn't allowed, but the code below is:

```
int number = 42;
int& numberRef = number;
```

Why can't the compiler treat an uninitialized reference variable like an uninitialized pointer? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: references can't be rebound: there's a syntactic-semantic ambiguity, and it's resolved by defining that assigning to a reference actually means assigning to the referred object, whereby the initialization of the reference merely binds the reference to the referred object.

Comment: If there would be uninitialized references why would we need them at all? We have pointers already.

Comment: @Drop, to avoid having to write the `->` in our code :)

Comment: is this C++ `int&`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a reference is uninitialized, there is no way to initialize it, since any attempt to assign to a reference always assigns to its referent.

```
int& numberRef;     // pretend this is allowed
numberRef = number; // copies number into some random memory location
```

Comment: Ah, I was overthinking it.. once again.